# Python: os.environ.get('SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND') returns None

Tags: python, ssh

Trying to follow a technique found at `bzr` and `gitosis` I did the following:

added to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` the `command="my_parser"` parameter
which point to a python script file named 'my_parser' and located in 
`/usr/local/bin`  (file was chmoded as 777)

in that script file `'/usr/local/bin/my_parser'` I got the following
lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
print os.environ.get('SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND', None)
```

When trying to ssh e.g. `ssh localhost`
I get `None` on the terminal and then the connection is closed.

I wonder if anyone have done such or alike in the past and can help me
with this.

Is there anything I should do in my python file in order to get that
environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` is set when you connect to a host with ssh to execute a single command:

```
$ ssh username@host 'some command'
```

Your "my_parser" would then return "some command".

Unless you invoke a shell with my_parser, it will then exit, and the connection will close. You can use this to control the environment of the remotely executed commands, but you lose the ability to have an interactive session